# How to change VSCode font

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VSCode.
I don't like that font VSCode is using for system, I don't know how to change VSCode sans-serif(system) font. I tried toggle developer tools, but you know it refreshes all stylesheets when you close/open it. Any solutions?

Comment: If you mean the Terminal font, you may try this setting: `"debug.console.fontFamily": "Consolas"`... else please specify which System font you're talking about.

Comment: there is a crapton of Q&A about changing fonts for VS Code: [`is:q [vscode] change font -size`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&pagesize=30&q=is%3aq%20%5bvscode%5d%20change%20font%20-editor%20-size&searchOn=3). Did you try searching for what you're looking for first?

Comment: if you're talking about UI font, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/519

Answer (score 2):

To change your Visual Studio Code Font:

Navigate

**File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings** -> **Commonly Used**

Scroll down to and find **Editor: Font Family**

[image]

The default value should be "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace" change this with your desired font.

This should automatically change your font in Visual Studio Code

Comment: No I mean the font is used for Interface: like used for Settings, Navigation bar, file names. I know how to change font for code.

Comment: Commonly used for you, but not necessarily for others

Answer (score 1):

1. Find workbench.desktop.main.css and edit it. The path varies based on your installation.

   - Local: C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench
   - Global: C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench
2. Search for the `.windows` solo class. Ignore entries with multiple classes.
3. Edit the value for `font-family` to set the font you want to use.

   - There are two entries for the `.windows` class. Make sure to edit the one with the `font-family` property. Ignore the `--monaco-monospace-font` property.
4. Keeping the CSS minified, save the file.
5. Restart VS Code.

Example:

```
// Original
.windows{font-family:Segoe WPC,Segoe UI,sans-serif;}

// Modified
.windows{font-family:Comic Sans MS,serif;}
```

Source: https://dev.to/kunaltanwar/how-to-change-vs-code-ui-font-in-windows-56mj

*Note*: You may need to do this every time VS Code updates since it will be flagged as corrupted.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_installation-appears-to-be-corrupt-unsupported

EDIT: Clarification on which property to target since there are multiple `.windows` classes.